# How to fix: Nodejs passport.header issue, req.session.passport undefined

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am currently having this error in my Development Server. This occurs on login attempts:

Is this passport specific issue. Please help, this works very well in production server

**I have this in my app.js**

```
app.use(cookieParser('12345678'));
app.use(session({ secret: '12345678', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true })); 
app.use(validator());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 
app.use(flash()); // flash - Initializing
app.use(compression()); 
app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app'), { maxAge: 7 * 86400000 }));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads'), { maxAge: 7 * 86400000 }));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.locals.pretty = false;
app.set('views', './views');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

**Then this in auth method**

```
module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, { id: user.id });
    });

    passport.use('site-register', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'pwd',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function (req, email, pwd, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {

            if( condition is ok){
                  return done(null, user, { message: 'Login Success' });
            }else{
              return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid Login, Please try another method to login' });
        }
   ));


   .....
}
```

**Then the issue:**

```
embah@devsertwo:~/node/nodeapp$ node app
Server turned on with development mode on port 3002
/home/embah/node/nodeapp/routes/auth.js:384
                                    req.session.passport.header = authHeader;
                                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'header' of undefined
    at /home/embah/node/nodeapp/routes/auth.js:384:65
    at /home/embah/node/nodeapp/controller/adaptor/mongodb.js:31:9
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/embah/node/nodeapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/quer
y.js:2180:28)
    at /home/embah/node/nodeapp/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /home/embah/node/nodeapp/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
embah@devsertwo:~/node/nodeapp$ Write failed: Connection reset by peer
```

**console.log(req.session) return below**

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Seems passport was never added

Comment: If you are not authenticated, you don't have the session object defined in your requests. Btw, it would be helpful if you can share you code.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the same code works in one environment but not the other leads me to believe it's an environment or configuration issue.

Maybe there's an incompatibility between some package versions that vary on production vs development? Try updating all your dependencies and see if anything changes.

Sometimes, changing the order of middleware can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your "node_modules" folder is not updated in development.
Delete the entire folder and run "npm i" (or with sudo if needed) again.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the passport auth in the main code itself and not exporting it. That will isolate the path issue. If that gives the same error, try reinstalling passportjs.

Comment: Sorry this is coming late. How do include passwportjs in main code